# With git, how do I reset the local deployment branch to origin's version?

Tags: git

I've got a local branch called `deployment`. This branch is also on `origin`. How do I reset the local deployment branch to the state of `origin`'s deployment branch?

Something like the following:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/deployment
```

Would that be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct, but be careful - `git reset --hard` throws away *all* uncommitted changes, i.e. those just in your working tree or the index (staging area).  Also, just make sure that you really are on the `deployment` branch with `git checkout deployment`, since `git reset` always changes the position of the current branch, i.e. the one that `HEAD` points to.

Comment: Thanks, one question in response to "since git reset always changes the position of the current branch": does this mean that there is no need for me to do `origin/deployment`? Instead I should do `git checkout deployment; git reset --hard origin`?

Comment: No, that doesn't follow.  `origin` is the name of a *remote* which is like a nickname for a URL to a repository.  `origin/development`, on the other hand, is a *remote-tracking branch*.  When you do `git fetch`, the remote-tracking branch `origin/development` will be updated to where the branch `development` is in the repository `origin`.  After doing that you would typically do (a) `git merge origin/development` (b) `git rebase origin/development` or (c) `git reset --hard origin/development` (if you want to throw away your local work and just use the latest version of development from origin)

Comment: @Tom: Another point: you can use the name of a remote (like `origin`) in a place where a commit is expected, but in that case it will be interpreted as a shorthand for `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`, not `refs/remotes/origin/development`, as you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance, that clarifies a lot. However, for some reason the `deployment` branch just does not seem to be set to the latest commit when I do `git reset --hard origin/deployment`. When I then do `git merge origin/deployment` it fast-forwards and then it does work. But the entire idea was that I wouldn't have to merge as I simply want to take over all remote changes and drop all local changes. Any idea on what I might be doing wrong, or anything else I can share with you?

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. There was another problem with my deploy script.